# web crawling using regex or xml libraries

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-crawler

I am trying to do webcrawler program using python. In this case, can we use regex to get the expected string or can we use the XML packages in python to get the string ?

I can see most of them are using regex. I like to know reason behind it.

Comment: I use RegEx for crawling (in general, not python. I use PHP) because its easier, at least for me, then using a 3th-party library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) Even better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1640661